# read object in java error java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC

Tags: java, serialization

Occur this error after print first record of the file-java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
I am tring to write object into file using below code and read all the object into the file

**Demo code**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Student implements Serializable
{
    int no;
    String nm;
    void set(int no,String nm)
    {
        this.no=no;
        this.nm=nm;
    }
    void get()
    {
        System.out.println(no+"--"+nm);
    }
}
class write
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int no;
            String s;
            ObjectOutputStream oi=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("d:\\abc1.txt",true));
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter Roll No:");
            no=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter Name:");
            sc.nextLine();
            s=sc.nextLine();
            Student s1=new Student();
            s1.set(no,s);
            oi.writeObject(s1);
            oi.close();
            Student sp;
            ObjectInputStream ooi=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("d:\\abc1.txt"));
            while((sp=(Student)ooi.readObject())!=null)
            {
                sp.get();
            }
            ooi.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to read all the object into the file.

Comment: I think your problem is because you're doing sc.nextLine() twice. The second one I think will read in the new line created when you press return. So you need to remove the one above s = sc.nextLine().

Answer (score 3):

Java serialization does not support "appending".  you can't write an ObjectOutputStream to a file, then open the file again in append mode and write another ObjectOutputStream to it.  you have to re-write the entire file *every time*.  (i.e. if you want to add objects to the file, you need to read all the existing objects, then write the file again with all the old objects and then the new objects).